How to pass arguments to multiple jobs at once in step functions?
I have multiple glue jobs all of them have same job parameters
--param1 and --param2 which are being used inside the glue jobs.
I connected both the glue jobs in steps functions.
But not sure how we can pass the params and access them inside the glue job.
I tried configuring them in definition
like
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "JobName": "Test1",
    "Arguments": {
      "--param1": "$.param1",
      "--param2": "$.param2"
    }
  },
  "Next": "Test2"
}

and similar thing for Test2 job as well.
But when starting the execution, if I provide below json as input, it is still printing "$.param1" and "$.param2" as parameter values.
{
  "param1": "value1",
  "param2": "value2"
}

How do I pass value1 and value2 as values for param1 and param2 for all the glue jobs while starting the execution of step function and access them inside glue job.Currently I'm accessing job params using below code
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', "param1", "param2"])
print("Test1", args["param1"], args["param2"])


{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "JobName": "Test1",
    "Arguments": {
      "--param1": <PARAM_1>,
      "--param2": <PARAM_2>
    }
  },
  "Next": "Test2"
}

I think the syntax is lightly diferent. A good way to check it is going to step functions services, create a new step function, using a template and filtering by glue: there's an example called AthenaIngestLargeDataset which contains an example of how parameters are passed to glue jobs:
{
  "Comment": "An example demonstrates how to ingest a large data set in Amazon S3 and partition it through aws Glue Crawlers, then execute Amazon Athena queries against that partition.",
  "StartAt": "Start Crawler",
  "States": {
    "Start Crawler": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Get Crawler status",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "<GLUE_CRAWLER_NAME>"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:startCrawler"
    },
    "Get Crawler status": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "<GLUE_CRAWLER_NAME>"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:getCrawler",
      "Next": "Check Crawler status"
    },
    "Check Crawler status": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Crawler.State",
          "StringEquals": "RUNNING",
          "Next": "Wait"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Start an Athena query"
    },
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 30,
      "Next": "Get Crawler status"
    },
    "Start an Athena query": {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueryString": "<ATHENA_QUERY_STRING>",
        "WorkGroup": "<ATHENA_WORKGROUP>"
      },
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Get query results"
    },
    "Get query results": {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:getQueryResults",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueryExecutionId.$": "$.QueryExecution.QueryExecutionId"
      },
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Send query results"
    },
    "Send query results": {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
      "Parameters": {
        "TopicArn": "arn:PARTITION:sns:REGION:ACCOUNT_NUMBER:MySnsTopic",
        "Message": {
          "Input.$": "$.ResultSet.Rows"
        }
      },
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}

